# how to use paste0() to get the column of a table in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, paste

I have a special situation to read a number of data frames using `assign()` in `for` loop. Then I need to access specific columns by using `paste0()` function when plotting. As a test, I could not simply use, for example, `head(paste0("a",2)$year)` to call column data. This gave an error: `Error: object 'year' not found`. I have also tried `head(paste0("a",2)[year]` but it did not work.

```
assign(paste0("a",2), read.table("ft_sim_10000Ne_20hapS_1E_50G_05i_20Chr_15Mb_1_1_MSFS.final.summary",header=T,sep="\t")
```

Here are the simplified codes I used.

```
library(gtools)
library(fs)
library(stringr)

pdf(paste0("combined.5rep.title.pdf"),width = 20, height = 25)
par(mfcol=c(5,5),mar=c(5,5,4,2)+0.2,cex.lab=1.6, cex.axis=1.3,lwd=2)
layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),nrow=5,ncol=5,byrow=T),width=c(1,1),height=c(1,1))

for (event in c("00d","01d","05d","09d","05i")){
        ## folder_name: 
        ## ft_sim_100000Ne_80hapS_1E_50G_05i_20Chr_15Mb_1_MSFS
        ## ft_sim_100000Ne_20hapS_1E_50G_00d_20Chr_15Mb_1_MSFS
        ## file_name in each folder
        ## ft_sim_100000Ne_20hapS_1E_50G_00d_20Chr_15Mb_1_1_MSFS.final.summary
        ## ft_sim_100000Ne_20hapS_1E_50G_00d_20Chr_15Mb_1_2_MSFS.final.summary
        a1 <- read.table(mixedsort(sort(fs::dir_ls(path=paste0("./ft_sim_10000Ne_20hapS_1E_50G_",event,"_20Chr_15Mb_1_MSFS"), recurse = TRUE, type = "file", glob = "*20hapS*50G*MSFS.final.summary"))),header=T,sep="\t")
        plot(a1$year,a1$Ne_median,type="l", col="red")
        ## add plot title in each plot
        mtext(side=3,text=paste0("10000Ne_20hapS_1E_50G_",event,"_20Chr_15Mb"),cex=0.8,line=1.2)
        ## add 4 replicate lines using for-loop
        for (rep in c(2:5)){
            assign(paste0("a",rep), read.table(mixedsort(sort(fs::dir_ls(path=paste0("./ft_sim_10000Ne_20hapS_1E_50G_",event,"_20Chr_15Mb_1_",rep,"_MSFS"), recurse = TRUE, type = "file", glob = "*20hapS*50G*MSFS.final.summary"))),header=T,sep="\t"))
            print(head(paste0("a",rep,n=2L)))
            lines(paste0("a",rep)$year,paste0("a",rep)$Ne_median,type="l", col="orange")
        }
}
dev.off()
```

My example data below:

```
mutation_per_site n_estimation theta_per_site_median theta_per_site_2.5. theta_per_site_97.5.          year Ne_median  Ne_2.5. Ne_97.5. Ne_12.5. Ne_87.5.
1     4.940656e-324          200          1.040995e-08        3.802781e-09         2.878802e-08 1.372405e-315 0.7229131 0.264082 1.999168 0.438941 1.505282
2      3.903363e-12          200          1.040995e-08        3.802781e-09         2.878802e-08  1.084268e-03 0.7229131 0.264082 1.999168 0.438941 1.505282
3      5.151705e-12          200          1.040995e-08        3.802781e-09         2.878802e-08  1.431029e-03 0.7229131 0.264082 1.999168 0.438941 1.505282
```

I did not find a solution to this problem. So my question is how I can get this solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question but I think using `get()` when accessing your data is what is missing.

```
head(get(paste0("a", 2))$year)
```

`paste0("a", 2)` gives the character value `"a2"`.

`get(paste0("a", "))` gives the value of the object named `a2`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, it works. What if there is a variable in `paste0("a", var)`? It seems not working.

Comment: It is hard to say without knowing the value of `var`, but if `var` is a vector containing more than 1 value, then it could cause an error.

Comment: It is a value of `rep` from the for-loop `for (rep in c(2:5)){}`.

Comment: Then I think it should work if you wrap the `paste0()` inside a `get()` function. But I do see that your code has `print(head(paste0("a",rep,n=2L)))` which looks like it should be `print(head(get(paste0("a",rep)),n=2L))`. (i.e the `n=2L` is an argument of `head()`, not `paste0()`.

Comment: This works again. Can you help with this line? `lines(get(paste0("a",rep)$year),get(paste0("a",rep)$Ne_median),type="l", col="orange")`, I got error `Error in paste0("a", rep)$year : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

Comment: Looks like the `)` after `year` should come before `$`. Same with `)` after `Ne_median`.